# How do I use the isValid method inside the move method to determine whether a move is legal?

Tags: java, methods, chess

(Java) - I have written out a lengthy, if incomplete, isValid method to determine whether moves in a game of chess are legal, but I have no idea how to embed the code into the move method so that if moves are entered that are illegal, the program prints a message to say the moves aren't valid and requests input again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Virtual_Chessboard {

    public enum Chessmen {
        WHITE_KING, WHITE_QUEEN, WHITE_ROOK, WHITE_BISHOP, WHITE_KNIGHT, WHITE_PAWN, BLACK_KING, BLACK_QUEEN, BLACK_ROOK, BLACK_BISHOP, BLACK_KNIGHT, BLACK_PAWN, EMPTY
    }

    public static Chessmen[][] chessboard = new Chessmen[8][8];

    public static void createBoard() {

        int rows = 8;
        int columns = 8;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == 7)) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.BLACK_ROOK;
                } else if ((i == 0 && j == 1) || (i == 0 && j == 6)) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.BLACK_KNIGHT;
                } else if ((i == 0 && j == 2) || (i == 0 && j == 5)) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.BLACK_BISHOP;
                } else if (i == 0 && j == 3) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.BLACK_KING;
                } else if (i == 0 && j == 4) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.BLACK_QUEEN;
                } else if ((i == 7 && j == 0) || (i == 7 && j == 7)) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.WHITE_ROOK;
                } else if ((i == 7 && j == 1) || (i == 7 && j == 6)) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.WHITE_KNIGHT;
                } else if ((i == 7 && j == 2) || (i == 7 && j == 5)) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.WHITE_BISHOP;
                } else if (i == 7 && j == 3) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.WHITE_KING;
                } else if (i == 7 && j == 4) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.WHITE_QUEEN;
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
                } else if (i == 6) {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
                } else {
                    chessboard[i][j] = Chessmen.EMPTY;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(Chessmen[][] chessboard) {
        int k = 8;
        System.out.print("   " + "\t" + "a" + "\t" + "b" + "\t" + "c" + "\t"
                + "d" + "\t" + "e" + "\t" + "f" + "\t" + "g" + "\t" + "h");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n" + k);
            k--;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t");
                switch (chessboard[i][j]) {
                case WHITE_KING:
                    System.out.print("\u2654");
                    break;
                case WHITE_QUEEN:
                    System.out.print("\u2655");
                    break;
                case WHITE_ROOK:
                    System.out.print("\u2656");
                    break;
                case WHITE_BISHOP:
                    System.out.print("\u2657");
                    break;
                case WHITE_KNIGHT:
                    System.out.print("\u2658");
                    break;
                case WHITE_PAWN:
                    System.out.print("\u2659");
                    break;
                case BLACK_KING:
                    System.out.print("\u265A");
                    break;
                case BLACK_QUEEN:
                    System.out.print("\u265B");
                    break;
                case BLACK_ROOK:
                    System.out.print("\u265C");
                    break;
                case BLACK_BISHOP:
                    System.out.print("\u265D");
                    break;
                case BLACK_KNIGHT:
                    System.out.print("\u265E");
                    break;
                case BLACK_PAWN:
                    System.out.print("\u265F");
                    break;
                case EMPTY:
                    System.out.print("");
                    break;

                } // switch

            } // / j for

        } // i for

    }

    public static void move(Chessmen[][] chessboard, String move) {



        char newj = move.charAt(6);
        int newi = Integer.parseInt(move.substring(7, 8));
        newi = -newi + 8;
        char oldj = move.charAt(0);
        int oldi = Integer.parseInt(move.substring(1, 2));
        oldi = -oldi + 8;

        switch (newj) {
        case 'a':
            newj = (int) 0;
            break;
        case 'b':
            newj = (int) 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            newj = (int) 2;
            break;
        case 'd':
            newj = (int) 3;
            break;
        case 'e':
            newj = (int) 4;
            break;
        case 'f':
            newj = (int) 5;
            break;
        case 'g':
            newj = (int) 6;
            break;
        case 'h':
            newj = (int) 7;
            break;
        }

        switch (oldj) {
        case 'a':
            oldj = (int) 0;
            break;
        case 'b':
            oldj = (int) 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            oldj = (int) 2;
            break;
        case 'd':
            oldj = (int) 3;
            break;
        case 'e':
            oldj = (int) 4;
            break;
        case 'f':
            oldj = (int) 5;
            break;
        case 'g':
            oldj = (int) 6;
            break;
        case 'h':
            oldj = (int) 7;
            break;
        }



        chessboard[newi][newj] = chessboard[oldi][oldj]; // Move
                                                                                            // piece
                                                                                            // to
                                                                                            // new
                                                                                            // position
        chessboard[oldi][oldj] = Chessmen.EMPTY;


    }

    public static boolean isValid(Chessmen[][] chessboard, int oldi,int oldj, int newi, int newj) {
        switch (chessboard[oldi][oldj]) {
        case WHITE_ROOK:
            if (oldi == newi || oldj == newj) {
                return true;
            } 
        case BLACK_ROOK : 
            if(oldi == newi || oldj == newj){
                return true;
            } 
        case WHITE_KNIGHT :
            if((newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj+1)|| (newi==oldi-2 && newj==oldj-1)||(newi==oldi-2 && newj==oldj+1)
            ||(newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj+2)||(newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj+2)||(newi==oldi+2 && newj==oldj+1)|| 
            (newi==oldi+2 && newj==oldj-1)||(newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj-2)){
                return true;
            }
        case BLACK_KNIGHT : 
            if((newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj+1)|| (newi==oldi-2 && newj==oldj-1)||(newi==oldi-2 && newj==oldj+1)
                    ||(newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj+2)||(newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj+2)||(newi==oldi+2 && newj==oldj+1)|| 
                    (newi==oldi+2 && newj==oldj-1)||(newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj-2)){
                        return true;
                    }
        case WHITE_BISHOP :
            for(int x =0;x<8;x++){
                if(newi==oldi+x && newj==oldj+x || newi==oldi-x && newj==oldj-x || newi==oldi+x && newj==oldj-x || newi==oldi-x && newj==oldj+x){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        case BLACK_BISHOP :
            for(int x =0;x<8;x++){
                if(newi==oldi+x && newj==oldj+x || newi==oldi-x && newj==oldj-x || newi==oldi+x && newj==oldj-x || newi==oldi-x && newj==oldj+x){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        case WHITE_KING :
            if((newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj) ||
                    (newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj+1) ||
                    (newi==oldi && newj==oldj+1) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj-1) ||
                    (newi==oldi && newj==oldj-1) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==newj+1) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==newj+1) ){
                return true;
            }
        case BLACK_KING :
            if((newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj) ||
                    (newi==oldi+1 && newj==oldj+1) ||
                    (newi==oldi && newj==oldj+1) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==oldj-1) ||
                    (newi==oldi && newj==oldj-1) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==newj+1) ||
                    (newi==oldi-1 && newj==newj+1) ){
                return true;
            }
        case WHITE_PAWN : 
            if(oldi==6 && newi<=4){
                return true;
            }
            else if(newi==oldi-1){
                return true;
            }
        case BLACK_PAWN :
            if(oldi==1 && newi<=3){
                return true;
            }
            else if(oldi==newi-1){
                return true;
            }

        default: return false;

        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        createBoard();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String command;

        while (!in.equals("exit")) {
            printBoard(chessboard);
            System.out.println("Please enter a move.");
            command = in.nextLine();
            move(chessboard, command);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not asking a bad question, but it is too broad for this help site. Also, your isValid method is buggy. Right at the start the rules for valid rook moves would allow White to use his rook to take the other players rook first move.

Comment: Also don't include a "Wall of Code".  For instance, we probably don't really need to see your `createBoard` and `printBoard` to help you out, and it's distracting.

Answer (score 0):

Move might look something like:

```
if (isValid(...)) {
    chessboard[newi][newj] = chessboard[oldi][oldj];
    chessboard[oldi][oldj] = Chessmen.EMPTY;
} else {
    throw new IllegalMoveException();
}
```

and then in your main function:

```
while (!in.equals("exit")) {
    printBoard(chessboard);
    System.out.println("Please enter a move.");
    command = in.nextLine();
    try {
        move(chessboard, command);
    } catch (IllegalMoveException e) {
        System.out.println("Illegal Move!");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If rewriting your entire code isn't an issue, I would recommend use a more object-oriented approach for this.

Ej. create a `Board` class with an array or 8x8 `Square` class instances, each of which, can contain an instance of a `Piece` class instance. Then, since the movements are made in the Board, you can implement a `boardInstance.movePiece(Piece pieceToMove, Square destinationSquare)` in which every `Piece` class should contain its movement rules so the `Board` instance knows if the `Piece` is movable to the destination `Square` instance.

Comment: OO code isn't really the way to go for chess software. To get the necessary speed out you will end up having to go with a bitboard representation (i.e. using long's to represent to board). Might as well do it from the start.

Comment: I don't really know if @jacka92 has performance concerns in its code but I have seen enough internet examples about OO chess games to consider that it shouldn't be a performance issue, considering it is not meant to be a Fritz-like or Deep Blue-like type of game.

Comment: I guess I was assuming the OP was writing a chess engine - if that's not the case and they just need the rules implemented then an OO solution would be far easier. For an actual chess engine though you can get about an order of magnitude performance improvement by using a bitboard.